# Qual a diferença de $('.botao').on('click') para $(document).on('click', '.botao')?

Tags: javascript, onclick, eventos-do-mouse

Dei uma procurada e não consegui achar nada sobre (provavelmente pq não estou sabendo como pesquisar). De qualquer forma, alguém ai sabe?

OBS: Eu não quero saber a diferença entre o .click e o .on('click'), leiam as duas opções com atenção por favor. O que quero saber é a diferença de referenciar o elemento que vai receber a ação antes de dizer qual a ação ou depois (colocando o document no lugar que antes ficava o elemento).

`$('.botao').on('click')` e `$(document).on('click', '.botao')`

Comment: O que entendeu da [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/on/) onde trata do segundo parâmetro da função?

Comment: Diego não é a mesma pergunta, eu tinha visto essa questão já, a dúvida dela é a diferença entre o .click e o on.('click'). A minha pergunta é sobre a diferença de colocar o $(document) no lugar do elemento que recebe a ação, e referenciar o elemento depois. Se você reparar as duas chamadas da minha questão usam o .on('click')..

Comment: Oi Thavi, a diferença nesse caso seria que '$('.botao')' voce está realizando uma ação apenas nessa classe, uso recomendado para quando deseja adicionar uma ação em um elemento especifico. 
Já o '$(document).on('click', '.botao')' você está executando a ação em toda a pagina no caso se tiver mais que um elemento com a classe botao na pagina e quando for clicada essa ação será acionada.
document = paginas.extensao
window = pagina carregada
.botao (apenas) = identificador do elemento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa o:

```
$('.botao').on('click');
```

Você esta vinculando o evento de click para cada elemento que contenha a class ".botao" já existente no documento. 
O principal problema deste método é que, caso você precise adicionar um elemento dinamicamente com a mesma class ".botao", **ele não vai possuir o evento de click**, pois foi adicionado ao documento posteriormente.

E quanto ao:

```
$(document).on('click', '.botao');
```

Neste caso, o evento de click esta vinculado ao documento em si, e não aos elementos específicos da class ".botao". Este é o método mais recomendado de se usar, pois quando adicionar novos elementos ao documento eles ainda terão a referência do evento de click vinculado ao documento.

Comment: Então na realidade a diferença é o que as pessoas estavam falando que era a diferença do .click e do on('click') [que na documentação do jquery diz serem iguais]...

Comment: Acredito que o .click e .on('click') são descritos como iguais pois realizam a mesma função. A diferença é mesmo no escopo em qual são aplicados (e no event target).

Comment: Entendi. Obrigada :D

Answer (score 2):

Veja esse exemplo: os botões 1 e 2 terão 2 alerts e o botão 3 somente um pois foi inserido posteriormente na DOM.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmJLrY